Get all the values of a particular key from Json file
[
   {
      "id":"0001",
      "type":"donut",
      "name":"Cake",
      "ppu":0.55,
      "batters":{
         "batter":[
            {
               "id":"1001",
               "type":"Regular"
            },
            {
               "id":"1002",
               "type":"Chocolate"
            }
         ]
      },
      "topping":[
         {
            "id":"5002",
            "type":"Glazed"
         }
         {
            "id":"5004",
            "type":"Maple"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"0002",
      "type":"donut",
      "name":"Raised",
      "ppu":0.55,
      "batters":{
         "batter":[
            {
               "id":"1001",
               "type":"Regular"
            }
         ]
      },
      "topping":[
         {
            "id":"5003",
            "type":"Chocolate"
         },
         {
            "id":"5004",
            "type":"Maple"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"0003",
      "type":"donut",
      "name":"Old Fashioned",
      "ppu":0.55,
      "batters":{
         "batter":[
            {
               "id":"1001",
               "type":"Regular"
            },
            {
               "id":"1002",
               "type":"Chocolate"
            }
         ]
      },
      "topping":[
         {
            "id":"5001",
            "type":"None"
         },
         {
            "id":"5004",
            "type":"Maple"
         }
      ]
   }
]

Expected output: [donut, Regular, Chocolate, Glazed, Maple, donut, Regular, Chocolate, Maple, donut, Regular, Chocolate, None, Maple]
Get all values of key(type) from above JSon into an array, including all children. Attached is the sample json and also expected output.
Is there any _lodash function for this or any Javascript function is also fine.

"all values of the key(type)" is just [donut, donut, donut]... You need to parse the batter and topping keys as well. What have you tried so far?

I think you need a recursive function for extract all values by key.

Be careful with large JSONs and memory.

function extractValuesByKey(obj, field) {
  if (!obj) return [];
  if (typeof obj !== "object") return [];
  if (Array.isArray(obj))
    return obj.map((value) => extractValuesByKey(value, field)).flat();

  let result = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (key === field) result.push(obj[key]);
    else result = result.concat(extractValuesByKey(obj[key], field));
  });
  return result;
}


Try This: 

Include Lodash via a CDN in your HTML file
he getAllValuesByKey function is defined to recursively search for the key type and collect its values.



 const data = [
         {
            "id": "0001",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Cake",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters": {
               "batter": [
                  {
                     "id": "1001",
                     "type": "Regular"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "1002",
                     "type": "Chocolate"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "topping": [
               {
                  "id": "5002",
                  "type": "Glazed"
               },
               {
                  "id": "5004",
                  "type": "Maple"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id": "0002",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Raised",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters": {
               "batter": [
                  {
                     "id": "1001",
                     "type": "Regular"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "topping": [
               {
                  "id": "5003",
                  "type": "Chocolate"
               },
               {
                  "id": "5004",
                  "type": "Maple"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id": "0003",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Old Fashioned",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters": {
               "batter": [
                  {
                     "id": "1001",
                     "type": "Regular"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": "1002",
                     "type": "Chocolate"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "topping": [
               {
                  "id": "5001",
                  "type": "None"
               },
               {
                  "id": "5004",
                  "type": "Maple"
               }
            ]
         }
      ];

      function getAllValuesByKey(obj, key) {
         const result = [];
         function recursiveSearch(obj) {
            if (_.isObject(obj)) {
               _.forOwn(obj, (value, k) => {
                  if (k === key) {
                     result.push(value);
                  }
                  recursiveSearch(value);
               });
            } else if (_.isArray(obj)) {
               obj.forEach(item => recursiveSearch(item));
            }
         }
         recursiveSearch(obj);
         return result;
      }

      const types = getAllValuesByKey(data, 'type');
      console.log(types); 
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Extract JSON Values</title>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>




Try this:
JSON.stringify([{"id":"0001","type":"donut","name":"Cake","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0002","type":"donut","name":"Raised","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0003","type":"donut","name":"Old Fashioned","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]}]).match(/(?<=["']type["']:\s*["'])(\w+)/g)

BTW, your json object is not in a correct format.
"topping":[
     {
        "id":"5002",
        "type":"Glazed"
     }
     {
        "id":"5004",
        "type":"Maple"
     }
  ]

There should be a comma between 5002 and 5004.

There are lots of examples to think of for which this wouldn't work.

This is a nice candidate for writing a generator function (and recursion):


function* valuesForKey(data, key) {
    if (Object(data) !== data) return; // It's not an object
    if (Object.hasOwn(data, key)) yield data[key];
    for (const child of Object.values(data)) yield* valuesForKey(child, key);
}

const data = [{"id":"0001","type":"donut","name":"Cake","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0002","type":"donut","name":"Raised","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]},{"id":"0003","type":"donut","name":"Old Fashioned","ppu":0.55,"batters":{"batter":[{"id":"1001","type":"Regular"},{"id":"1002","type":"Chocolate"}]},"topping":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]}];
const keys = [...valuesForKey(data, "type")];
console.log(keys);



